# Is there a tool to validate HTML in standards mode?

Tags: html, standards

Is there any tool that can validate if my web page is build to standards mode, and can highlight/point out non-standard HTML?

Comment: A simple search would have brought back lots of tools.  Try putting some effort in

Comment: @Pete, Well... I searched in stackoverflow and not in Google. Thanks... I really was being naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [W3c Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) runs your code against the W3c specification.

Comment: And I got this too... https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: I still use Henri Sivonen's original HTML5 conformance checker. I like the minimalist interface: https://validator.nu/